# How can i make combo box to list all values with a text i type in vb

Tags: vb.net

[combo box sample for country list when "n" is type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9R00.png)Assuming i have a list (Nigeria, Germany, Canada, England, Portugal) in my combo box and i want the combo box to work in the sense that if i type "n", there should be a dropdown list for all values with "n" instead of showing only Nigeria that start with "n"

Comment: have you tried any code about it? add to the question if any

Comment: no, i only tried all the properties for combo box

Comment: The search term you want for Google is "vb.net combobox custom autocomplete".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using WinForms, then set the ComboBox .AutoCompleteMode property to either Suggest, Append or SuggestAppend (try each to see which you prefer, I tend to use SuggestAppend) then set the AutoCompleteSource to ListItems.

In visual sudio you can do this by selecting the ComboBox and setting these in the Properties window.

Comment: I've tried all i could do with the whole properties of combo box, but not working out

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim countryList() As String = {"nigeria", "germany", "canada", "england", "Portugal"}

    Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyPress
        Dim listToDisplay As New List(Of String)
        Dim charTyped As Char = e.KeyChar

        ComboBox1.Text = ""
        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()

        If (Asc(charTyped) >= 65 And Asc(charTyped) <= 90) Or (Asc(charTyped) >= 97 And Asc(charTyped) <= 122) Then 'if character typed is a-z or A-Z

            For Each i As String In countryList
                If i.ToUpper.Contains(CStr(charTyped).ToUpper) Then
                    listToDisplay.Add(i)
                End If
            Next

            For Each i As String In listToDisplay
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)
            Next
        Else
            For Each i As String In countryList
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        For Each i As String In countryList
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: this is not really what i'm talking about, i want the autocomplete property to work in the sense that if i type "an" it will drop down both canada, germany, and england.

Comment: I do not believe Autocomplete will solve your issue. According to  [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode?view=netframework-4.8): "Use the AutoCompleteCustomSource, AutoCompleteMode, and AutoCompleteSource properties to create a TextBox that automatically completes input strings by comparing the **prefix** being entered to the **prefixes** of all strings in a maintained source."